# Improve performance of Fuzzywuzzy between two large datasets

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have installed the apache spark on my machine to run it locally.
My machine has this specifications:
2,3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
16 GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4X

So, I configured a local spark session -> local[6].

My problem is:
I have to match two large spark datasets based on strings. One has 2.4M records and the other one has 38k records. I have used the Fuzzywuzzy library for python 3.9 and the performance of my code is really bad. I am running this matching for 7 hours and it has not finished yet.

I would like to find the best match in the smaller dataset to complete the info in the large dataset. So, I concatenated the info in the large dataset that I want to search in the smaller dataset and applied the process.extractBests(). I know there is a lot of comparisons to do but I have not found any other solution to try to minimize this number of comparisons. On the other hand, I feel I am not taking advantage of parallel processing.
Could you please give me some advice?

```
header1 = ["name_make_ad", "name_model_ad", "name_fueltype_ad", "engine_capacity_ccm", "engine_power_km",
                    "engine_power_kw", "name_transmission_ad", "name_body_ad", "name_drivetype_ad", "nr_door_ad",
                    "nr_seats_ad"]

header2 = ["name_make", "name_model", "name_fueltype", "cap_ccm", "pwr_km_base", "pwr_kw_base",
                     "name_transmission_et", "name_body_et", "name_drivetype_et", "cnt_door", "cnt_seat", "id"]

dataset1 = df1.withColumn("concatenated1", F.concat_ws(", ", *[F.col(x) for x in header1]))

dataset2 = df2 \
    .withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .withColumn("concatenated2", F.concat_ws(", ", *[F.col(x) for x in header2]))

matches = []
list1 = df1.select("header1").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

list2 = df2.select("header2").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

for item1 in list1:
    matches.append((item1,process.extractBests(item1, list2, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff=50, limit=2)[0][0]
                    .split(", ")[-1]))
dfIndexes = sparkSession.createDataFrame(matches).toDF("header1","id")
dfAdsIndexed = df1.join(dfIndexes, on="header1", how="inner").drop("header1")
dfMapping = dfAdsIndexed.join(df2, on="id", how="inner").drop("header2","id")
```

**dataset1:**

| name_make_ad | name_model_ad | prod_year_ad | name_fueltype_ad | engine_capacity_ccm | engine_power_km | engine_power_kw | name_transmission_ad | name_body_ad | name_drivetype_ad | name_color_ad | nr_door_ad | nr_seats_ad | mileage_ad | currency_ad | price_ad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fiat | freemont | 2016 | diesel | 1956.0 | 170.0 | 125.0 | automatic | suv | all-wheel-auto | grey | 5 | 7 | 82000.0 | PLN | 66500.0 |
| fiat | freemont | 2015 | diesel | 1956.0 | 170.0 | 125.0 | manual | suv | front-wheel | grey | 5 | 7 | 140000.0 | PLN | 64900.0 |
| fiat | freemont | 2013 | diesel | 1956.0 | 140.0 | 103.0 | manual | suv | front-wheel | black | 5 | 7 | 189000.0 | PLN | 47970.0 |

**dataset2:**

| name_make | name_model | modnamegrp2 | name_vehtype_et | y_modbegin | y_modend | name_body_et | cnt_seat | cnt_door | name_fueltype | pwr_km_base | pwr_kw_base | pwr_km_hyb | pwr_kw_hyb | cap_ccm | torque_base | torque_hyb | cnt_hyb | name_drivetype_et | name_transmission_et |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Petrol | 170 | 125 | 0 | 0 | 2360 | 220 | 0 | 0 | Front wheel drive | Automatic transmission |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Petrol | 280 | 206 | 0 | 0 | 3605 | 342 | 0 | 0 | 4 wheel drive general | Automatic transmission |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Diesel | 170 | 125 | 0 | 0 | 1956 | 350 | 0 | 0 | 4 wheel drive general | Automatic transmission |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 5 | 5 | Petrol | 170 | 125 | 0 | 0 | 2360 | 220 | 0 | 0 | Front wheel drive | Automatic transmission |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Diesel | 170 | 125 | 0 | 0 | 1956 | 350 | 0 | 0 | Front wheel drive | Manual gearbox |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Diesel | 140 | 103 | 0 | 0 | 1956 | 350 | 0 | 0 | Front wheel drive | Manual gearbox |

So, I have to find out for each record in dataset1, what is the best match on dataset2 based on similarity.

**The output for this example would be:**

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Diesel | 170 | 125 | 0 | 0 | 1956 | 350 | 0 | 0 | 4 wheel drive general | Automatic transmission |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Diesel | 170 | 125 | 0 | 0 | 1956 | 350 | 0 | 0 | Front wheel drive | Manual gearbox |
| FIAT | Freemont | Freemont | Passenger Car | 2011 | 2016 | Van | 7 | 5 | Diesel | 140 | 103 | 0 | 0 | 1956 | 350 | 0 | 0 | Front wheel drive | Manual gearbox |

Comment: Give rapidfuzz a try... - https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `collect` and subsequent `for` loop are not parallelized by Spark. Hence, the performance degradation. You can apply a cartesian join on `df1` and `df2` and then invoke a `udf` to score each row. Finally, you can order based on the score and choose the `top` n rows.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

cutoff = 50
max_matches = 1

@udf(returnType=DoubleType()) 
def scorer(query: str, choice: str):
    match_score = list(process.extractWithoutOrder(query, [choice], scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff=cutoff))
    if len(match_score) == 0:
        return 0.0
    return float(match_score[0][1])

df_1_data = [("fiat", "freemont", 2016, "diesel", 1956.0, 170.0, 125.0, "automatic", "suv", "all-wheel-auto", "grey", 5, 7, 82000.0, "PLN", 66500.0),
("fiat", "freemont", 2015, "diesel", 1956.0, 170.0, 125.0, "manual", "suv", "front-wheel", "grey", 5, 7, 140000.0, "PLN", 64900.0),
("fiat", "freemont", 2013, "diesel", 1956.0, 140.0, 103.0, "manual", "suv", "front-wheel", "lack", 5, 7, 189000.0, "PLN", 47970.0),]

df_2_data = [("FIAT", "Freemont", "Freemont", "Passenger Car", 2011, 2016, "Van", 7, 5, "Petrol", 170, 125, 0, 0, 2360, 220, 0, 0, "Front wheel drive", "Automatic transmission"),
("FIAT", "Freemont", "Freemont", "Passenger Car", 2011, 2016, "Van", 7, 5, "Petrol", 280, 206, 0, 0, 3605, 342, 0, 0, "4 wheel drive general", "Automatic transmission"),
("FIAT", "Freemont", "Freemont", "Passenger Car", 2011, 2016, "Van", 7, 5, "Diesel", 170, 125, 0, 0, 1956, 350, 0, 0, "4 wheel drive general", "Automatic transmission"),
("FIAT", "Freemont", "Freemont", "Passenger Car", 2011, 2016, "Van", 5, 5, "Petrol", 170, 125, 0, 0, 2360, 220, 0, 0, "Front wheel drive", "Automatic transmission"),
("FIAT", "Freemont", "Freemont", "Passenger Car", 2011, 2016, "Van", 7, 5, "Diesel", 170, 125, 0, 0, 1956, 350, 0, 0, "Front wheel drive", "Manual gearbox"),
("FIAT", "Freemont", "Freemont", "Passenger Car", 2011, 2016, "Van", 7, 5, "Diesel", 140, 103, 0, 0, 1956, 350, 0, 0, "Front wheel drive", "Manual gearbox"),]


header1 = ["name_make_ad", "name_model_ad", "name_fueltype_ad", "engine_capacity_ccm", "engine_power_km",
                    "engine_power_kw", "name_transmission_ad", "name_body_ad", "name_drivetype_ad", "nr_door_ad",
                    "nr_seats_ad"]

header2 = ["name_make", "name_model", "name_fueltype", "cap_ccm", "pwr_km_base", "pwr_kw_base",
                     "name_transmission_et", "name_body_et", "name_drivetype_et", "cnt_door", "cnt_seat"]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_1_data, ("name_make_ad", "name_model_ad", "prod_year_ad", "name_fueltype_ad", "engine_capacity_ccm", "engine_power_km", "engine_power_kw", "name_transmission_ad", "name_body_ad", "name_drivetype_ad", "name_color_ad", "nr_door_ad", "nr_seats_ad", "mileage_ad", "currency_ad", "price_ad",))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df_2_data, ("name_make", "name_model", "modnamegrp2", "name_vehtype_et", "y_modbegin", "y_modend", "name_body_et", "cnt_seat", "cnt_door", "name_fueltype", "pwr_km_base", "pwr_kw_base", "pwr_km_hyb", "pwr_kw_hyb", "cap_ccm", "torque_base", "torque_hyb", "cnt_hyb",  "name_drivetype_et",  "name_transmission_et",))

dataset1 = df1.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())\
              .withColumn("concatenated1", F.concat_ws(", ", *[F.col(x) for x in header1]))

dataset2 = df2.withColumn("concatenated2", F.concat_ws(", ", *[F.col(x) for x in header2]))

combined_df = F.broadcast(dataset1).crossJoin(dataset2)

df_score_matching_cutoff = combined_df.withColumn("fuzz_score", scorer(col("concatenated1"), col("concatenated2")))\
                      .filter(col("fuzz_score") >= cutoff)

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.desc("fuzz_score"))

results = df_score_matching_cutoff.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(window_spec))\
                        .filter(col("rn") <= max_matches)

results.show(truncate=False)
```

### Output

```
+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---+
|name_make_ad|name_model_ad|prod_year_ad|name_fueltype_ad|engine_capacity_ccm|engine_power_km|engine_power_kw|name_transmission_ad|name_body_ad|name_drivetype_ad|name_color_ad|nr_door_ad|nr_seats_ad|mileage_ad|currency_ad|price_ad|id |concatenated1                                                                     |name_make|name_model|modnamegrp2|name_vehtype_et|y_modbegin|y_modend|name_body_et|cnt_seat|cnt_door|name_fueltype|pwr_km_base|pwr_kw_base|pwr_km_hyb|pwr_kw_hyb|cap_ccm|torque_base|torque_hyb|cnt_hyb|name_drivetype_et    |name_transmission_et  |concatenated2                                                                                   |fuzz_score|rn |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---+
|fiat        |freemont     |2016        |diesel          |1956.0             |170.0          |125.0          |automatic           |suv         |all-wheel-auto   |grey         |5         |7          |82000.0   |PLN        |66500.0 |0  |fiat, freemont, diesel, 1956.0, 170.0, 125.0, automatic, suv, all-wheel-auto, 5, 7|FIAT     |Freemont  |Freemont   |Passenger Car  |2011      |2016    |Van         |7       |5       |Diesel       |170        |125        |0         |0         |1956   |350        |0         |0      |4 wheel drive general|Automatic transmission|FIAT, Freemont, Diesel, 1956, 170, 125, Automatic transmission, Van, 4 wheel drive general, 5, 7|88.0      |1  |
|fiat        |freemont     |2015        |diesel          |1956.0             |170.0          |125.0          |manual              |suv         |front-wheel      |grey         |5         |7          |140000.0  |PLN        |64900.0 |1  |fiat, freemont, diesel, 1956.0, 170.0, 125.0, manual, suv, front-wheel, 5, 7      |FIAT     |Freemont  |Freemont   |Passenger Car  |2011      |2016    |Van         |7       |5       |Diesel       |170        |125        |0         |0         |1956   |350        |0         |0      |Front wheel drive    |Manual gearbox        |FIAT, Freemont, Diesel, 1956, 170, 125, Manual gearbox, Van, Front wheel drive, 5, 7            |95.0      |1  |
|fiat        |freemont     |2013        |diesel          |1956.0             |140.0          |103.0          |manual              |suv         |front-wheel      |lack         |5         |7          |189000.0  |PLN        |47970.0 |2  |fiat, freemont, diesel, 1956.0, 140.0, 103.0, manual, suv, front-wheel, 5, 7      |FIAT     |Freemont  |Freemont   |Passenger Car  |2011      |2016    |Van         |7       |5       |Diesel       |140        |103        |0         |0         |1956   |350        |0         |0      |Front wheel drive    |Manual gearbox        |FIAT, Freemont, Diesel, 1956, 140, 103, Manual gearbox, Van, Front wheel drive, 5, 7            |95.0      |1  |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---+
```

Comment: I have shared some data for dataset1 and dataset2 and how the output should look like for the best match based on similarity. Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you have chance to take a look?

Comment: I should have a working example within 2 hours.

Comment: @jorgemaagomes updated answers with working example.

Comment: if I have a spark cluster with these features:

 .config("spark.executor.instances", 10) 
 .config("spark.executor.cores", 3) 
 .config("spark.executor.memory", "10g") 

Should I partition dataset1 with 10 or more (.reparition(10))?
What is the best approach regarding the number of partitions on datasets considering the number of executors available?

Comment: Since `dataset1` has only 38k, repartitioning does not make a lot of sense, since we are applying a `cross join`. Moreover `dataset1` has the `broadcast` hint so that if possible Spark can push the entire dataset to all partitions of `dataset2`. You can however re-partition `dataset2`(with 2.4 M records) depending on the size of each partition after joining.